# Why is docker stats CPU Percentage greater than 100 times number of cores

Tags: azure, docker, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM with 2 cores. From my understanding, the CPU % returned by `docker stats` can be greater than 100% if multiple cores are used. So, this should max out at 200% for this VM. However, I get results like this with CPU % greater than 1000%

```
CONTAINER           CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT       MEM %               NET I/O               BLOCK I/O             PIDS
545d4c69028f        3.54%               94.39 MiB / 6.803 GiB   1.35%               3.36 MB / 1.442 MB    1.565 MB / 5.673 MB   6
008893e3f70c        625.00%             191.3 MiB / 6.803 GiB   2.75%               0 B / 0 B             0 B / 24.58 kB        35
f49c94dc4567        0.10%               46.85 MiB / 6.803 GiB   0.67%               2.614 MB / 5.01 MB    61.44 kB / 0 B        31
08415d81c355        0.00%               28.76 MiB / 6.803 GiB   0.41%               619.1 kB / 3.701 MB   0 B / 0 B             11
03f54d35a5f8        1.04%               136.5 MiB / 6.803 GiB   1.96%               83.94 MB / 7.721 MB   0 B / 0 B             22
f92faa7321d8        0.15%               19.29 MiB / 6.803 GiB   0.28%               552.5 kB / 758.6 kB   0 B / 2.798 MB        7
2f4a27cc3e44        0.07%               303.8 MiB / 6.803 GiB   4.36%               32.52 MB / 20.27 MB   2.195 MB / 0 B        11
ac96bc45044a        0.00%               19.34 MiB / 6.803 GiB   0.28%               37.28 kB / 12.76 kB   0 B / 3.633 MB        7
7c1a45e92f52        2.20%               356.9 MiB / 6.803 GiB   5.12%               86.36 MB / 156.2 MB   806.9 kB / 0 B        16
0bc4f319b721        14.98%              101.8 MiB / 6.803 GiB   1.46%               138.1 MB / 64.33 MB   0 B / 73.74 MB        75
66aa24598d27        2269.46%            1.269 GiB / 6.803 GiB   18.65%              1.102 GB / 256.4 MB   14.34 MB / 3.412 MB   50
```

I can verify there are only two cores:

```
$ grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo
2
```

The output of `lshw -short` is also confusing to me:

```
H/W path      Device           Class      Description
=====================================================
                               system     Virtual Machine
/0                             bus        Virtual Machine
/0/0                           memory     64KiB BIOS
/0/5                           processor  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2673 v3 @ 2.40GHz
/0/6                           processor  Xeon (None)
/0/7                           processor  (None)
/0/8                           processor  (None)
/0/9                           processor  (None)
/0/a                           processor  (None)
/0/b                           processor  (None)
/0/c                           processor  (None)
/0/d                           processor  (None)
/0/e                           processor  (None)
/0/f                           processor  (None)
/0/10                          processor  (None)
...
```

with well over 50 processors listed

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I would suggest you to submit an issue on [this page](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues).

> The output of lshw -short is also confusing to me:

If you omit the "-short" parameter, you will find that all of the "processor (None)" is in the state of DISABLED.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, issue opened [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/28941)